# Xamarin: Change value of GridItemLayout in codebehind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
 <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="collectionViewItemsLayout" ItemsSource="{Binding BaseCustomersCards}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerCardTemplateSelector}" >
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="5" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView>
```

I've  got this collectionview but am attempting to change the span for phone-tablet. Default is 5 but phone value should be 3.

```
  var idiom = DeviceInfo.Idiom;
            if (idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
            {
                collectionViewItemsLayout.SetValue(GridItemsLayout.SpanProperty, 3);
            }
```

I made this in the code-behind to change it, the method triggers but doesn't change anything. I've tried to put the 3 as a string and as pure value. I've also attempted to put the x:name in the attribute but it cannot go there.

Comment: i think you should add a name to the GridItemsLayout " <GridItemsLayout x:Name="gridItemsLayout"  Orientation="Vertical" Span="5" />" and then in your code gridItemsLayout.SetValue(GridItemsLayout.SpanProperty, 3);

Comment: If I do it there, it just say gridItemsLayout does not exist in this context. I.e can't seem to access the gridItemsLayout directly like that

Comment: Sorry I dont have xamarin installed what about collectionViewItemsLayout.ItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(3, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout

Comment: Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic. You should be able to bind to a dynamic resource and then set that resource depending on the device it's running on.

Answer (score 2):

Works by creating a new GridItem and setting it instead

```
 if (idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
            {
                var grid = new GridItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
                {
                    Span = 3,
                };

                collectionViewItemsLayout.SetValue(CollectionView.ItemsLayoutProperty, grid);
            }
```